# QGIS enhanced table labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, attribute-table

I would like to know how I can save enhanced labels of the attribute table.
I got a QGIS Project from a third person. Within a layer of this project, I can see enhanced table labels. I already found out that in this Project-folder there is a .QML-file which contains the style I guess.
But everytime when I try to change the label names for example to "gemarkungsname" it is switching the label automatically back to "gemarkungs". Even when I save it as a style-file it is directly switching the label back after I saved it.
So how can I set up a label with more than 10 letters?

Answer (score 2):

Fieldnames of shapefiles are only 10 characters long at most. You may add "display"-fieldnames, which can be longer and are saved within the project and/or `.qml` file. The field itself within the shapefile still has it's original 10 character name, which is used by the expression/label.